# Running all Combinations of Dummy Variables Through a Regression Equation

Tags: r, regression

I have an issue that concerns itself with extracting output from a regression for all possible combinations of dummy variable while keeping the continuous predictor variables fixed.

The problem is that my model contains over 100 combinations of interactions and manually calculating all of these will be quite tedious. Is there an efficient method for iteratively calculating output?

The only way I can think of is to write a loop that generates all desired combinations to subsequently feed into the `predict()` function.

***Some context:***

I am trying to identify the regional differences of automobile resale prices by the model of car.

My model looks something like this:

```
lm(data, price ~ age + mileage + region_dummy_1 + ... + region_dummy_n + model_dummy_1 + ... + model_dummy_n + region_dummy_1 * model_dummy_1 + ... + region_dummy_1 * model_dummy_n)
```

***My question is:***

How do I produce a table of predicted prices for every model/region combination?

Comment: so what is your question again? writing the model?

Comment: I am trying to find predicted prices for every model/region combination. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sorry, but still unclear. What's wrong by predict function

Comment: I want every single combination of model/region with Age and Mileage at a fixed level. I can do this with predict, but it is exceptionally tedious. I want to know if there are any functions or suggestions for loops to avoid having to provide inputs every time I wish to do this.

Comment: what are the values that region dummy and model dummy take?

Comment: They are both binary dummies so 0 or 1.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `expand.grid` function.  This with take multiple vectors of values and generate every permutation.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `.*.`

```
lm(price ~ .*.)
```

---

## Here's a small reproducible example:

```
> df <- data.frame(y  = rnorm(100,0,1),
+                  x1 = rnorm(100,0,1),
+                  x2 = rnorm(100,0,1),
+                  x3 = rnorm(100,0,1))
> 
> lm(y ~ .*., data = df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ . * ., data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3        x1:x2        x1:x3  
   -0.02036      0.08147      0.02354     -0.03055      0.05752     -0.02399  
      x2:x3  
    0.24065
```

---

## How does it work?

`.` is shorthand for "all predictors", and `*` includes the two-way interaction term.

For example, consider a dataframe with 3 columns: **Y (independent variable)**, and **2 predictors (X1 and X2)**. The syntax `lm(Y ~ X1*X2)` is shorthand for `lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1:X2)`, where, `X1:X2` is the interaction term.

Extending this simple case, imagine we have a data frame with 3 predictors, **X1, X2, and X3**. `lm(Y ~ .*.)` is equivalent to `lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X1:X2 + X1:X3 + X2:X3)`.

Comment: A very useful shortcut! I'm afraid my question was not clear enough. I already have my model. I am trying to use the model to produce predicted prices for all combinations of region and car model given a fixed age and mileage.